# DELETE relation when using FOREACH in neo4j

Tags: performance, foreach, neo4j

I need to DELETE relations of particular type of a node which is iterating over FOREACH.

In detail ::

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Label1)-[r1:REL1]-(a:Label2) 
WHERE a.prop1 = 2 
WITH n 
WITH COLLECT(n) AS rows 
WITH [a IN rows WHERE a.prop2 < 1484764200] AS less_than_rows, 
[b IN rows WHERE b.prop2 = 1484764200 AND b.prop3 < 2] AS other_rows 
WITH size(less_than_rows) + size(other_rows) AS count, less_than_rows, other_rows
FOREACH (sub IN less_than_rows | 
  MERGE (sub)-[r:REL2]-(:Label2) 
  DELETE r 
  MERGE(l2:Label2{id:540}) 
  MERGE (sub)-[:APPEND_TO {s:0}]->(l2) 
  SET sub.prop3=1, sub.prop2=1484764200) 
WITH DISTINCT other_rows, count 
FOREACH (sub IN other_rows | 
  MERGE(l2:Label2{id:540}) 
  MERGE (sub)-[:APPEND_TO {s:0}]->(l2) 
  SET sub.prop3=sub.prop3+1)
RETURN count
```

As FOREACH is not suppoting MATCH, I used MERGE to achieve it. But it is very slow when I execute it (It is taking around 1 min).
But If I excete with out FOREACH (stop updaing), it is giving around 1 sec.

**Problem:: Clearly the problem with FOREACH or inside operations with in FOREACH.
I want to delete a particular relation, create another relation and set some properties to node.**

Note:: I showed total query because Is there any other way to achieve the same requirement (out of this FOREACH, I tried with CASE WHEN)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a few things about your original query:

- `MERGE(l2:Label2 {id:540})` should be moved out of both `FOREACH` clauses, since it only needs to be done once. This is slowing down the query. In fact, if you expect the node to already exist, you can use a `MATCH` instead.
- `MERGE (sub)-[:APPEND_TO {s:0}]->(l2)` may not do what you intended, since it will only match existing relationships in which the `s` property is still `0`. If `s` is not `0`, you will end up creating an additional relationship. To ensure that there is a single relationship and that its `s` value is (reset to) `0`, you should remove the `{s:0}` test from the pattern and use `SET` to set the `s` value; this should also speed up the `MERGE`, since it will not need to do a property value test.

This version of your query should fix the above issues, and be faster (but you will have to try it out to see how much faster):

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n:Label1)-[:REL1]-(a:Label2)
WHERE a.prop1 = 2
WITH COLLECT(n) AS rows
WITH
  [a IN rows WHERE a.prop2 < 1484764200] AS less_than_rows, 
  [b IN rows WHERE b.prop2 = 1484764200 AND b.prop3 < 2] AS other_rows 
WITH size(less_than_rows) + size(other_rows) AS count, less_than_rows, other_rows
MERGE(l2:Label2 {id:540}) 
FOREACH (sub IN less_than_rows | 
  MERGE (sub)-[r:REL2]-(:Label2) 
  DELETE r 
  MERGE (sub)-[r2:APPEND_TO]->(l2)
  SET r2.s = 0, sub.prop3 = 1, sub.prop2 = 1484764200) 
WITH DISTINCT l2, other_rows, count 
FOREACH (sub IN other_rows | 
  MERGE (sub)-[r3:APPEND_TO]->(l2) 
  SET r3.s = 0, sub.prop3 = sub.prop3+1)
RETURN count;
```

If you only intend to set the `s` value to 0 when the `APPEND_TO` relationship is being created, then use the `ON CREATE` clause instead of `SET`:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n:Label1)-[:REL1]-(a:Label2)
WHERE a.prop1 = 2
WITH COLLECT(n) AS rows
WITH
  [a IN rows WHERE a.prop2 < 1484764200] AS less_than_rows, 
  [b IN rows WHERE b.prop2 = 1484764200 AND b.prop3 < 2] AS other_rows 
WITH size(less_than_rows) + size(other_rows) AS count, less_than_rows, other_rows
MERGE(l2:Label2 {id:540}) 
FOREACH (sub IN less_than_rows | 
  MERGE (sub)-[r:REL2]-(:Label2) 
  DELETE r 
  MERGE (sub)-[r2:APPEND_TO]->(l2)
  ON CREATE SET r2.s = 0
  SET sub.prop3 = 1, sub.prop2 = 1484764200) 
WITH DISTINCT l2, other_rows, count 
FOREACH (sub IN other_rows | 
  MERGE (sub)-[r3:APPEND_TO]->(l2)
  ON CREATE r3.s = 0
  SET sub.prop3 = sub.prop3+1)
RETURN count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FOREACH, you can UNWIND the collection of rows and process those. You can also use OPTIONAL MATCH instead of MERGE, so you avoid the fallback creation behavior of MERGE when a match isn't found. See how this compares:

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Label1)-[:REL1]-(a:Label2) 
WHERE a.prop1 = 2 
WITH COLLECT(n) AS rows 
WITH [a IN rows WHERE a.prop2 < 1484764200] AS less_than_rows, 
[b IN rows WHERE b.prop2 = 1484764200 AND b.prop3 < 2] AS other_rows 
WITH size(less_than_rows) + size(other_rows) AS count, less_than_rows, other_rows
// faster to do it here, only 1 row so it executes once
MERGE(l2:Label2{id:540}) 
UNWIND less_than_rows as sub
OPTIONAL MATCH (sub)-[r:REL2]-(:Label2) 
DELETE r 
MERGE (sub)-[:APPEND_TO {s:0}]->(l2) 
SET sub.prop3=1, sub.prop2=1484764200
WITH DISTINCT other_rows, count, l2
UNWIND other_rows as sub
MERGE (sub)-[:APPEND_TO {s:0}]->(l2) 
SET sub.prop3=sub.prop3+1
RETURN count
```

Comment: cybersam had a good point about moving the MERGE of l2 from the loop. Even though my query doesn't have a FOREACH, I moved it above the UNWIND, so it only gets executed once on one row, instead of for every row after the UNWIND.